# Laravel Vue component not refreshing after running gulp

Tags: laravel, gulp, browser-cache, vue-component

I have a custom Vue component set up in my Laravel 5.3 app.  It works fine, but I have to do a cache refresh in my browser in order for any changes to my component to appear after I run gulp.  This is annoying while I am developing, and won't be acceptable for deployment.  Is there some sort of directive I need in my gulpfile or elsewhere to make the cache busting happen automatically?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might seem like a dumb question or maybe I'm totally missing the question but are you using elixir?

**gulpfile.js**

```
.scripts('my-file.vue.js', 'public/js/my-file.vue.js', 'resources/assets/js')
```

*later in your file...*

```
.version(['js/my-file.vue.js', (...)]);
```

**in your blade:**

```
<script src="{{ elixir('js/my-file.vue.js') }}"></script>
```

**Note:** Please read the comments below this answer to see the path to the solution as it might give you more clarity than just reading it straight up.

Comment: Yes, I'm using elixir, and I am using webpack to compile my vue components.  I have a .webpack('app.js'), but no .version('app.js').  Do I need to version each of the vue files independently as your post here suggests, or can I just version app.js as a whole?  And do I do that before or after the .webpack call?

Comment: Versioning a file is required because by doing so every time you modify your files a new hash will be created thus you will be "forcing" a cache as your old files won't be there. I cannot help you with webpack as this moment due to my lack of knowledge in it. It's in my bucket list for the next few days though. Check your public file and see the names of your javascript. If they are not something like my-file.iasjdsadas7dasd.js then you're not versioning :). You can version by .version() simply.

Comment: I'd like to add something though: Webpack might have a way to not need the files to be versioned through 'npm run dev' or so. I'm not totally comfortable giving this answer but I did a very light search on the subject.

Comment: Ok, I changed my gulpfile to have the .webpack call before my .version call, and added 'public/js/app.js' (the final output of the webpack call) to the list of scripts and styles in my .version call.  That appears to have fixed the issue!  (I mention moving the .webpack call because I first tried just adding a second .version call after my .webpack call, and that ended up putting things in weird places that broke things.  Making just one .version call and including the .webpack output in the list did the trick, though.)

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but it might be worth editing it to make a note directing future readers to read the comments as well.

Comment: Added it. There might be another solution to this issue if either of us gets to know it come back here and update it :)